# Posting comments into a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post a comment which in turn insert into a join table `comment_post_join` where it then binds itself to a post.

```
comment_post_join
  post_id
  comment_id
```

I am posting the correct values as I am parsing both the post_id and also the comment_id and have checked the values are correct by doing a print_r on the $_POST.

I am trying to update by posting like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="'<?php echo($id); ?>'" />
```

And the action script goes...

```
if ($r) { 

$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];   

$comment_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc); 

$query = "INSERT INTO comment_post_join (`comment_id`, `post_id`) VALUES ($comment_id, $post_id)";

    var_dump($query);
    exit();

mysqli_query($dbc, $query); 
mysqli_close($dbc); 



// REDIRECT BACK TO DOCUMENT LIST 
echo("<script>location.href = 'employee_forum.php';</script>"); 
}
```

I am assuming the issue is with the INSERT query as I am clearly doing something wrong here.

I am getting this on the var_dump();

`string(74) "INSERT INTO comment_post_join (`comment_id`,`post_id`) VALUES ('1', '37')"`

So I know it is posting the correct values form the post_id and comment_id

Comment: Your query is good! did you try to run the query in a phpmyadmin directly?

Comment: I sure did and it was failing on me - think some silly human error was involved here - Cris kindly suggested a fix and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you uncomment the fields like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comment_post_join (comment_id, post_id) VALUES ($comment_id, $post_id)";
```